# Application Insights Kusto (KQL): How to sort items produced by make_set operator

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to group different kinds by a version. Here is the simplest repro/example:

```
let Source = datatable(Name:string, Version:string)
[
    'Car', '1.0.0',
    'Train', '2.0.0',
    'Train', '1.0.0',
    'Car', '2.0.0'
];
Source
| summarize make_set(Name) by Version
```

Right now the the kinds appear according to the order of individual records:

[image]

As a result it is hard to compare lines. Wonder how to make items sorted in make_set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `array_sort_asc()` / `array_sort_desc()`:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraysortascfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraysortdescfunction

For example:

```
let Source = datatable(Name:string, Version:string)
[
    'Car', '1.0.0',
    'Train', '2.0.0',
    'Train', '1.0.0',
    'Car', '2.0.0'
];
Source
| summarize Names = array_sort_asc(make_set(Name)) by Version
```